# Handle hashbang (#!) in asp.net mvc3(Routing)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing single page application using hashbangs(#!)
So the application urls are in format #!/api/generalelections.
When i directly enter this url in browser the mvc does not seem to recognize hashbangs ,it always take me to default action mentiond in glolab.asax.
Could anyone provide me solution to handle this problem to redirect to proper action which is api/generalelections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that goes after `#` is treated by browser as anchor tag and will not be supplied to the server.

In your Xhr requests to the server you should use 'normal' uris, but not your navigation ones.